# Как из функции read файловой системы /proc получить доступ к приватным данным драйвера

Tags: linux, c, драйвер, kernel

Хочу выдавать некую отладочную информацию в файл виртуальной ФС */proc*. Для этого я должен передать ядру коллбэк на функцию  такой сигнатуры:

```
static ssize_t myread(struct file *file, char __user *ubuf,size_t count, loff_t *ppos)
{
    printk( KERN_DEBUG "read handler\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Все подготовительные операции я сделал, файлик в */proc* создаётся и когда я его пытаюсь читать, в *syslog* выводится сообщение "read handler".

Пора на этот скелет навешивать полезное мясо. Однако, возникала проблема: все данные, которые я хочу отображать через ВФС */proc* располагаются в приватной области драйвера, которая создавалась при инициализации драйвера функцией *probe()*. Поскольку все функции драйвера, которые вызываются ядром, получают в первом параметре указатель на *struct pci_dev*, то никаких проблем с доступом к к приватным данным не возникает.

Функции чтения/записи устройства, которое управляется моим драйвером, получают указатель на описатель файла, в котором есть указатель на драйвер, в котром есть указатель на приватные данные. Проблем нет!

Но функция *myread(...)* получает в первом параметре описатель файла ВФС */proc*, а вовсе не моего драйвера. И получить доступ к моим приватным данным из неё я не могу.

Вопрос: как получить доступ к приватным данным драйвера из функции чтения файловой системы */proc* ?

Comment: Прочитать исходники модулей, где это работает? https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/rtc/proc.c#L81

Comment: @0andriy А знаете, в этом исходном тексте даже нет вызова функции *create_proc_entry*.. Т.е. этот текст к виртуальной ФС */proc* не имеет **никакого** отношения. Когда нечего сказать, может быть лучше промолчать?

Comment: @Sergey, `create_proc_entry` задеприкатели уже довольно давно... если под болей-менее современные ядра писать, то используй `proc_create_data`, передавай указатель на `struct pci_dev`, а в `myread` получай через `PDE_DATA(file_inode(file));`... для совсем свежих ядер можешь сделать как предлагает *0andriy* — на самом деле это хороший вариант для простых случаев... а для совсем старых, то ЕМНИП там придётся сохранять в какой-нить глобальной переменной/списке...

Comment: @Fat-Zer "передавай указатель на *struct pci_dev* - так я и спрашиваю, где же его взять ?! В процедуре *read* из */proc* ? А насчёт *PDE_DATA(file_inode(file))* я не уверен, но вот здесь (http://tuxthink.blogspot.com/2013/10/creation-of-proc-entrt-using.html) с помощью этого макро получают доступ к **пользовательским** данным в юсерспейс. А вовсе не к **приватным** данным драйвера. Так что, спасибо за информацию, но это мимо моей проблемы.

Comment: @Fat-Zer *create_proc_entry задеприкатели уже довольно давно.* - не помню точно,  но там, куда я пишу этот драйвер, стоит какая-то четвёрка с хвостиком... И ничего - не ругается.

Comment: @Fat-Zer *придётся сохранять в какой-нить глобальной переменной* - Разумеется, это первое, что приходит в голову. Я пока соорудил костыль такого типа, но он раздражает мои эстетические чувства :-)

Comment: @Sergey, странно, что не ругается... сейчас посмотрел — в 3.10 его с концами удалили... или «четвёрка» — это 2.4?

Comment: @Fat-Zer *это 2.4* :-)  Нет! Вот содержимое каталога */usr/src>* :



   *kernel-modules  linux-4.4.179-99      linux-4.4.180-102*

Comment: @Sergey, и `PDE_DATA` возвращает как раз «пользовательские» данные драйвера, которые были переданы в `proc_create_data`... к юзерспейсу оно не имеют отношения, так что здесь это как раз то что нужно...

Comment: @Fat-Zer *PDE_DATA возвращает как раз «пользовательские» данные драйвера* - проверил. Всё работает отлично. Спасибо за подсказку! Оформите в виде ответа - я Вам галку поставлю!

Comment: @Sergey, лучше сам оформи... я в ближайшие насколько дней скорей всего не осилю написать...